# How can i use apt-get install without interrupting? While assigning with large package lists

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, package-management

I have a line "apt-get install package1 ... package60", now once any one of the package is missing i want that it simply ignore that package and still continue.

How to do that? in Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--ignore-missing` will do the trick for you.